# Update Label before next Function execution

Tags: python, label

I want to use a Label Text to inform the User, why He/She is waiting at that Moment. (LDAPS Authorisation etc.)
For that i update a Label with a StringVar() and a Trace/Callback, before I start the Function that will have some Waiting Time.

But I dont get the new Label Text before the Function is done.

None Code Explanation:

1. Label Entry State ("Empty")
2. Label Change -> ("First Change")
3. Function Call

   3.a 1. Label Change in Function -> ("One")

   3.b 2. Label Change in Function -> ("Two")

All I see is the last Change ("Two"), even if I check if the Label Text is ("First Change") as condition to start the Function.

If I comment out the Function, it works like intended.

Here are my Code Parts:

```
def callback(log_string):
            print(log_string.get())
        
        
log_string = StringVar(lower_frame,"Leer","LogString")
log_string.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode, log_string = log_string: callback(log_string))
```

```
def msg_getvalues_starter():
            print('msg_getvalues_starter activated')
            log_string.set('LDAPS Überprüfung')
            print(log_output.cget("text"))
            print('compare result : ',log_output["text"] == 'LDAPS Überprüfung')
            if log_output["text"] == 'LDAPS Überprüfung':
                print('log_outupt == LDAPS Überprüfung')
                msg_getvalues()
```

So after the If Condition the Text of the Label is correctly set, but not shown.

I tried some Sleep but didnt helped.

I would like to know, what i can do about the Timing ?

Comment: What's up with that lambda? Never seen one like that

Comment: Good Question :) I am new in Python, so sometimes I learn while trying and Looking at other Code Examples...
Normaly I only would use the 'w' Mode and the Callback...